# Adding line breaks using sendemail in a flow

Tags: email, workflow

Hi I am using the sendEmail from the flow sample pack to send an email under specific conditions. This is working. How ever the email content is not keeping the linebreaks as entered by the user during flow runtime.

I am using a long text area to enter the note.

Thanks in advance Barry

The Apex class creates a string called body from data passed by the flow as follows:

```
  String body = (String) request.inputParameters.get('body');
```

and uses it in a sendEmail method as follows:

```
  message.setHtmlBody(body != null ? body : '');  // If the body is empty, use an empty string
```

Comment: sample code will help .How is body being referenced in apex ?

Comment: The flow is the "Send Email Apex Plug-in Sample" from the sales force flow samplepack

Comment: @MohithKumar the code for Send Email is .....

Comment: I edited to add the code, but I am wondering if this is just something funny about how the RTE creates the HTML for the body. Can you look at the code that is being created by the RTE and passed from the flow?

Answer (score 3):

The line breaks the user is entering is more than likely plain text `\r\n`... but you need `<br />` for the html body. Try setting the email plain text body and see if the line breaks are working. If so, this could be a possible solution:

```
String body = ((String)request.inputParameters.get('body')).replace('\r\n','<br \>');
```

If this was helpful please mark as answered. Thanks!